# Transformation using XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

Need help to convert SOAP message to XML:
The element "externalID"can occur multiple time so based on "externalID"  this element need to generate "Detail" tag in output XML.

Need some code sample to convert this SOAP message to desired output XML
Input SOAP Message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mem="http://example.com/vc/types/attachments">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mem:payRequest>
         <payload>
            <uuid>?</uuid>
            <umi>?</umi>
            <externalID>
               <externalLineID></externalLineID>
               <groupNo>?</groupNo>
               <payeeCd>dfsdfsfd</payeeCd>
               <paymntAmt>?</paymntAmt>
               <acctCd>dfafa</acctCd>
               <transID>fasf</transID>
               <errCD>?</errCD>
               <errMessage>?</errMessage>
            </externalID>
            <externalID>
               <externalLineID>?</externalLineID>
               <groupNo>?</groupNo>
               <payeeCd>dfsdfsfd</payeeCd>
               <paymntAmt>?</paymntAmt>
               <acctCd>dfafa</acctCd>
               <transID>fasf</transID>
               <errCD>?</errCD>
               <errMessage>?</errMessage>
            </externalID>
            <errCD>?</errCD>
            <errMessage>?</errMe`enter code here`ssage>
         </payload>
      </mem:payRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

==============

Desired Output XML:

```
<payRequest>
    <Detail>
        <uuid>?</uuid>
        <umd>?</umd>
        <claimNumber></claimNumber>
        <claimLineNumber>?</claimLineNumber>
        <dd>1</dd>
        <claimStatus></claimStatus>
        <clientNumber></clientNumber>
        <payMode>Other</payMode>
        <paymentAmount></paymentAmount>
        <accountCode></accountCode>
        <transactionId></transactionId>
        <errorCode></errorCode>
        <returnCode></returnCode>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <uuid>?</uuid>
        <umd>?</umd>
        <claimNumber></claimNumber>
        <claimLineNumber>?</claimLineNumber>
        <dd>1</dd>
        <claimStatus></claimStatus>
        <clientNumber></clientNumber>
        <payMode>Other</payMode>
        <paymentAmount></paymentAmount>
        <accountCode></accountCode>
        <transactionId></transactionId>
        <errorCode></errorCode>
        <returnCode></returnCode>
    </Detail>
</payRequest>
```

Comment: "*Need some code sample*" is not a question.

Comment: Hi Michael ,Basically i was trying to Transform this above SOAP message to XML i am facing challnege while creating the tag "Detail" based on the incoming tag "externalID" and this tag is array so need to built that "Detail" array in output XML. Can you please help me how to do this transformation.

Comment: Post your attempt so can we fix it, instead of writing everything from scratch.

Comment: i am trying to do mapping for one field only. below is my XSLT.
<xsl:template match="/">
<payClaimsRequest>
<xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='externalID']">
<Detail>
   <claimLineNumber><xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='payClaimsRequest']/*[local-name()='payload']/*[local-name()='externalID']/*[local-name()='externalLineID']"/></claimLineNumber>
   
  </Detail>
</xsl:for-each>
</payClaimsRequest>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you try it along these lines:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
     <payRequest>
         <xsl:for-each select="//externalID">
            <Detail>            
                <uuid>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../uuid"/>
                </uuid>
                <umd>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../umi"/>
                </umd>
                <claimNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="XYZ"/>
                </claimNumber>
                <claimLineNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="externalLineID"/>
                </claimLineNumber>
                <dd>
                    <xsl:value-of select="XYZ"/>
                </dd>
                <claimStatus>
                    <xsl:value-of select="XYZ"/>
                </claimStatus>
                <clientNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="XYZ"/>
                </clientNumber>
                <payMode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="XYZ"/>
                </payMode>
                <paymentAmount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="paymntAmt"/>
                </paymentAmount>
                <accountCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="XYZ"/>
                </accountCode>
                <transactionId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="transID"/>
                </transactionId>
                <errorCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="errCD"/>
                </errorCode>
                <returnCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="XYZ"/>
                </returnCode>
            </Detail>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </payRequest>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You did not provide any information regarding which source nodes are supposed to provide the data for the result. I have tried to guess a few and used `XYZ` as a placeholder for the others.

**Note**: you should never have to use a hack like `*[local-name()='externalID']`.

Comment: Thanks Michael,  I tried the way you suggested and it is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Michael, I accepted the answer , But not sure like how to close this. Thanks once again for your response.